# How to get php variable from an action form and use it in the form thats activating the action

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two files here as a test the first one which is this below and when I click submit it suppose to do the action on the next page but I want to know how to get retrieve athe $life variable from the action php file and put it in the normal html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form class="" action="../logic/profileAction.php" method="post">
<label for=""></label>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second file which is the php file:

```
<?php
$life ="Yo";
 ?>
```

Comment: your question not clear. you want to show $life variable in first file after submit?

Comment: Your question is a bit general, would you post the full code please

Comment: your form do not sends any data to profileAction.php. So what do you expect to become?

Comment: if you want to show $life variable then include second file in first file

Comment: Why don't you simply $life in the html file  ?! What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I just want to be able to use the $life variable in the first html like print it out

Comment: I am going to do an edit and I want to retrieve the values from the database and put it as placeholders

Comment: Why don't you put  "Yo"  in html itself ?

Comment: Ok...so simply use php query to get results in the html file and put them in place holders...simple...why submit form to another file ?

Comment: To have the value of a PHP var on the client side, simply echo it, as was already mentioned. To be able to retain it across submits, you can put it in a hidden input, which then will get sent along with the other controls. `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $life;?>" name="life">`

Answer (score 0):

check this code. you need to run this code in server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  include_once 'edit.php';
  echo $life;
  ?>

<form class="" action="../logic/profileAction.php" method="post">
<label for=""></label>
  <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is your include edit.php

```
<?php
$life = 'Ok';
?>
```

then your first file show ok when you run this code